# issue with nuget install not installing all files

Tags: nuget

I'm using nuget and octopus to deploy a nodejs app. So I created a nuget package from a nuspec file that has includes specific files ie:

```
    file src="package.json" target="package.json" 
    file src="app.js" target="app.js" 
    file src="app\**\*" target="app" 
    ...
```

when deploying from octopus everything gets deployed property. When doing a nuget install from the command line, everything gets deployed except the package.json file

and if I look in the nuget package file, the json file is there.

does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: looks like if I name the package.json file anything other than package.json (ie _package.json) it works...

Answer (score 0):

This is a NuGet issue, which has been tracked at https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4139.